# c and uinput, how to handle different languages

Tags: android, c, linux

Maybe this is a dumb question, but before I start coding this part of my software I'm looking for some clarifications.

My applications let the user write on a client app browser based to write on Android. While I've written all the necessary code to handle this stuff, I don't know how to handle different languages selected on the phone.

I mean, on my phone to make a COLON (:) I need to send a SHIFT (RIGHT SHIFT -> CODE 54) and a DOT (.)(CODE 52), but this is the same for every language? Will it be the same on an Android phone with English language enabled?

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Are you asking about matching whatever the user entered on the Android virtual keyboard to a key code?

Answer (score 1):

The events you are sending using the `uinput` interface are essentially key presses and releases and the [codes](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/event-codes.txt) are *key codes*, not characters. The key codes are standardized, with the actual keyboard driver being responsible for converting the low-level hardware codes (also known as scan codes) to the proper key code.

As such, the whole subsystem is language agnostic, with the international character-set mapping support generally being provided either by the userspace (e.g. the X server) or the upper layers of the kernel (e.g. the virtual console subsystem).

Since you are generating your own events using `uinput`, you are essentially emulating a hardware keyboard and you are, therefore, responsible for matching whatever was actually entered to the proper key code.

If you are relaying the events from an existing actual or virtual keyboard, you have two options:

- Find a way to receive raw events with the proper keycodes from the kernel. On a full-blown Linux distribution that could be accomplished via the [`evdev`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/input/input.txt) interface. I am unsure if that functionality is available on Android.
- Find a way to receive key codes from a standard language-agnostic set and convert them to Linux key codes. For example, X key codes are also unaffected by the keyboard mapping, as opposed to *keyboard symbols*.
- Translate whatever your application is receiving. Now this is tricky - you would have to be aware of the keyboard mapping and you may also have difficulty with the modifier keys (e.g. Shift), since those may not always be passed to the application.

Comment: My problem is exactly that: i need to send key codes that match the characted that has been pressed on the client. After posting i started looking around and i founded that i can load the keyboard character map directly from the kernel, the only thing i need to do is a reverse mapping becase the kernel map is from KEY CODE to CHARACTER but i need to reverse it to get CHARACTER -> SEQUENCE OF KEY CODES (i've to handle modifiers too)
Using KDSKBENT and KDGKBDIACR ioctls (linux/kd.h) i should be able to build the character map and reverse it.

Comment: @daniele_dll: 1. are you sure that the kernel keyboard map is used by the Android UI? Android could very well have its own interfaces. 2. How will you deal with special keys like e.g. `Shift` or `->` ? Some of them may not even exist on the Android virtual keyboard...

Comment: Well, good question :) Initially i've thinked about this but i've done some (really simple) tests and the android ui printed out stuff seems to match the kernel character map, i mean i send a sequence of key codes (including modifiers like shift, alt, ctrl and so on) and the right characters appeared on the screen.
However i'm trying to port dumpkeys (part of kdbtools) to extract a character map and test every single character to see if it match in the UI.